# Installing real time patch for Ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: 20.04, kernel, dpkg, raspberrypi

I am trying to install a real time patch on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi. Unfortunately none of my trials worked. Each of my attempts ends with the attached error message after trying to install the compiled deb packages. Please let me know if you need more information.

After downloading and applying the patch I copy the old config file and run the following commands:

```
cp /boot/config-5.X.X.X-raspi .config
make oldconfig  # select PREEMPT-RT
make -j8 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-raspi KDEB_PKGVERSION=$(make kernelversion)-1
```

Error message that occurs when installing the compiled .deb files:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/kernel_main$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-5.4.193-rt74-raspi_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi-dbg_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb linux-libc-dev_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb                                                                                 (Reading database ...   
126243 files and directories currently installed.)   
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.4.193-rt74-raspi_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb ...  
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.193-rt74-raspi (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) over (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...   
Preparing to unpack linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi-dbg_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb ...   
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi-dbg (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) over (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...  
Preparing to unpack linux-libc-dev_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb ...   
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:arm64 (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) over (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...    
Preparing to unpack linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi_5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1_arm64.deb ...                                    
Unpacking linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) over (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...   
Setting up linux-headers-5.4.193-rt74-raspi (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ... 
Setting up linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi-dbg (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...    
Setting up linux-libc-dev:arm64 (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...  
Setting up linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi (5.4.193-rt74-raspi-1) ...  
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.193-rt74-raspi   
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb    
Couldn't find DTB bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb on the following paths:   
 /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi /lib/firmware/5.4.193-rt74-raspi/device-tree/    
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.4.193-rt74-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb   
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory  
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1    
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1    
Using DTB: bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb  
Couldn't find DTB bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb on the following paths:   
 /etc/flash-kernel/dtbs /usr/lib/linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi /lib/firmware/5.4.193-rt74-raspi/device-tree/  
Installing  into /boot/dtbs/5.4.193-rt74-raspi/./bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb  
cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory   
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-flash-kernel exited with return code 1    
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi (--install):    
 installed linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1      
Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-5.4.193-rt74-raspi
```